# PouchDB + Cloudant + Ionic2 - Works on browser, error on sim/device

Tags: ionic2, pouchdb, cloudant

I'm building an ionic2 app that uses local PouchDB and interacts with a Cloudant db. On the browser the app works fine, but on the iOS simulator, I get the following error.
[ionic run ios -c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vB1Sp.png) and
[safari console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo7Qo.png)

The code is as follows:

```
getHives() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.db.query('DesignDoc/ViewName', {
        include_docs: true,
        attachments: true,
        key: this.loggedInUser

      }).then(result => {

        this.someList = [];
        result.rows.map((row) => {
          console.log("Row : " + JSON.stringify(row));
          if (row.doc.type == "someCondition") {
            this.someList.push(row);
          }
        });
        resolve(this.someList);

        this.db.changes({
          live: true,
          since: 'now',
          include_docs: true,
          attachments: true,
          filter: '_view',
          view: 'DesignDoc/ViewName',
          key: this.loggedInUser

        }).on('change', (change) => {
          this.handleChange(change);
        });
      });

    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log("Error : " + error);
    });
  }
```

Can someone help me with what's going wrong here...also what's the _local/xyz...text after my cloudant URL ?

Thanks.

Comment: I created a new Ionic 2 app (Cloudant/CouchDB 2.0.0) and am unable to reproduce issue. I had a similar stacktrace when running from the browser, but that was related to my CORS configuration (which should not be an issue on iOS). The _local endpoint is used for replication. Are you using any of the replication or sync APIs in pouchdb?

Comment: Is 10.10.11.125 your local machine, and are you trying to connect to that from the iOS simulator? This could be a CORS issue. If you have your CORS in Cloudant set up for localhost:8100 that will work locally, but not from the simulator.

Comment: The CORS I understand should be enabled, I made that setting on cloudant (running on IBM Bluemix). Yes, 10.10.11.125 is my local machine but the iOS simulator should connect to the Bluemix cloudant...is the problem that its looking for cloudant on 10.10.11.125 ? I have a sync running with the remote db, thanks for the explanation on _local.

Comment: OK. I am able to reproduce this when using the --livereload option. I see similar output in my log. When I do not use the --livereload option it works fine. I can verify this in the system log (from Simulator click Debug > System log), or by running the xcodeproj generated by Ionic in Xcode. Give it a try without livereload and see if you still experience the issue.

Comment: I removed the --livereload but the error remains. The number of times I get the 404 error is much lesser now, but I still get the error and no documents are being fetched from cloudant.

Comment: Ok, I did something additional...removed the ajax timeout options from the db calls. Now its working. Thanks a ton @markwatsonatx.